# Complex SQL query - sum of field in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b46ea/2

Current SQL:

```
SELECT `vehicle_journey`.*,
    ADDTIME(departure, SEC_TO_TIME((1))) AS stopDepartureTime
FROM `vehicle_journey`
INNER JOIN `vehicle_journey_days`
    ON `vehicle_journey_days`.`journey_reference` = `vehicle_journey`.`reference`
INNER JOIN `journey_pattern`
    ON `journey_pattern`.`reference` = `vehicle_journey`.`journey_pattern_reference`
INNER JOIN `journey_pattern_timing_link`
    ON `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`section` = `journey_pattern`.`journey_pattern_section`
WHERE `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`stop` = '1900HA030193'
    AND `vehicle_journey_days`.`day` = 'MondayToFriday'
```

The final aim of this SQL statement is to get the arrival time of a bus based on its `departure` time in `vehicle_journey` and the `run_time` in `journey_pattern_timing_link`.

The reason this is proving difficult and why I'm asking for help is because of the nature of the `journey_pattern_timing_link` table. The table is set up to provide the time in seconds it takes to get from one stop to the next (this is so that times are relative to each departure time).

As you will see in the select statement I'm not far from it. The 'ADDTIME' function is where the bus stop's departure time will be calculated. But, you will see a '1' in the value to add to the departure time. This is just a placeholder, essentially it's inside that SEC_TO_TIME function that I need to add up and work out the departure time.

But wait, what are we adding up? Well this is what I meant about the nature of the `journey_pattern_timing_link` table. What I need to do is get the total of all the run_time fields inside the `journey_pattern_timing_link` table where the ID is LESS than the one of the selected stop in the where statement AND the `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`section` is equal to the one based on the join.

I understand this is a very long question and one that requires a lot of thought but I am well and truly stuck. Looking at the SQL Fiddle's schema browser should help to understand the table structure.

Comment: +1 for the SQL Fiddle. There aren't many SQL questions that provide this, so it's great to see once in a while a question that has this.

Comment: @RaduGheorghui Thanks Radu. I think it would be impossible to even look at this question without one!

Comment: SQL Fiddle is really cool. Actually, I didn't know that.

Comment: Just FYI, if it was me, I'd think about storing `day` as a bit integer, where 1 = Monday, 4 = Wednesday, 5 = Monday & Wednesday, and 127 = daily

Comment: @Strawberry Yes that's actually something I plan to do! Thanks for pointing out, it's something I need to change in the parser that imports this data.

Comment: IN your fiddle you dont have a 1900HA030193

Comment: @Mihai Try changing the stop to: '1900HA080982' and the day to: 'Saturday'

Comment: Based on your new conditions the original fiddle returns 3 rows.Which row`id should  be taken into account?

Comment: @Mihai All 3, I'd need to generate a stopDepartureTime field for each vehicle journey.

Comment: So, are you looking at something almost like creating a check book?  The journey starts at 0, after first run is X time, then show second run so total running time is from the X + Y, then X + Y + Z for third stop?  Or cumulative X + delay before Y starts + Y + delay before Z starts + Z.  Slightly different queries, but hopefully better clarification of what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it. It does a second join onto `journey_pattern_timing_link` to get all the stops that are up to and including the stop you are looking for, then sum their `run_time` and add it to `departure`:

```
SELECT 
  `vehicle_journey`.*,
  ADDTIME(departure,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`previous_stops`.`run_time`))) `duration`  
FROM `vehicle_journey`
INNER JOIN `vehicle_journey_days`
    ON `vehicle_journey_days`.`journey_reference` = `vehicle_journey`.`reference`
INNER JOIN `journey_pattern`
    ON `journey_pattern`.`reference` = `vehicle_journey`.`journey_pattern_reference`
INNER JOIN `journey_pattern_timing_link`
    ON `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`section` = `journey_pattern`.`journey_pattern_section`
LEFT JOIN `journey_pattern_timing_link` `previous_stops`
    ON `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`section` = `previous_stops`.`section`
    AND `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`id` >= `previous_stops`.`id`
WHERE `journey_pattern_timing_link`.`stop` = '1900HA080987'
    AND `vehicle_journey_days`.`day` = 'Saturday'
GROUP BY
  `vehicle_journey`.`id`,
  `vehicle_journey`.`journey_pattern_reference`,
  `vehicle_journey`.`departure`,
  `vehicle_journey`.`service_reference`,
  `vehicle_journey`.`reference`,
  `vehicle_journey`.`code`
```

Comment: This also works but I have to reward best answer to Kickstart as he posted just 2 minutes before. Thanks so much for your answer, though!

Comment: It appears I can't even tell the difference between two times, I have changed the best answer :P

Answer (score 3):

Try this, although SQL fiddle seems to struggle with it:-

```
SELECT vehicle_journey.id, 
        vehicle_journey.journey_pattern_reference, 
        vehicle_journey.departure, 
        vehicle_journey.service_reference, 
        vehicle_journey.reference, 
        vehicle_journey.code, 
        vehicle_journey_days.day,
        TIME(ADDTIME(departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(jptl2.run_time)))) AS stopDepartureTime
FROM vehicle_journey
INNER JOIN vehicle_journey_days ON vehicle_journey_days.journey_reference = vehicle_journey.reference
INNER JOIN journey_pattern ON journey_pattern.reference = vehicle_journey.journey_pattern_reference
INNER JOIN journey_pattern_timing_link ON journey_pattern_timing_link.section = journey_pattern.journey_pattern_section AND journey_pattern_timing_link.stop = '1900HA080102' 
INNER JOIN journey_pattern_timing_link  jptl2 ON jptl2.section = journey_pattern.journey_pattern_section AND jptl2.ID <= journey_pattern_timing_link.ID
WHERE vehicle_journey_days.day = 'Saturday'
GROUP BY vehicle_journey.id, vehicle_journey.journey_pattern_reference, vehicle_journey.departure, vehicle_journey.service_reference, vehicle_journey.reference, vehicle_journey.code
```

Comment: I am so very grateful for your answer, you have absolutely no idea! Thank you soooooooooo much

Comment: Thanks for the vote, but @Tobsey did reply a fraction before me. As both our answers seem to be functionally the same (with really just minor style differences), they probably deserve the acceptance rather than me.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty! I did check myself before awarding the answer and it seems I failed to tell the difference between who answered first, sorry to tease! I do prefer the style of your answer, however.